# Changing the tree by inserting a duplicate node on each nodes's .left

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

A function doubleTree() does this : Changes the tree by inserting a duplicate node  on each nodes's .left.

[As explained here](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html)

My question is what if change the call function to like that in order traversal

```
doubleTree(node.left);

// duplicate this node to its left 
oldLeft = node.left; 
node.left = new Node(node.data); 
node.left.left = oldLeft; 

doubleTree(node.right);
```

I do not think outcome is going to change. Please correct me if I am wrong. And what about the performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think performance and outcome will change. Since we are iterating entire tree, time complexity of both the approaches is O(N)